# Move address data into separate table

Tags: database-design, normalization

Currently address information is stored directly in the `OrderHeader` and `Customer` tables.  I would like to create a separate `Address` table and replace the current address information with a reference to the primary key of that table (`AddressId`).

The database already contains data (thousands of rows) and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I only figured out how to transfer the data over into the address table with the code below.

`INSERT INTO Address (Address, City, State, ZipCode, AddressType)`

`SELECT Customer.Address,Customer.City,Customer.State,Customer.ZipCode,'Home' ASAddressType`

`FROM Customer`

`UNION ALL`

`SELECT OrderHeader.ShipAddress, OrderHeader.ShipCity, OrderHeader.ShipState, OrderHeader.ZipCode, 'Home' AS AddressType`

`FROM OrderHeader;`

[image: What I have tried]

[image: Starting Schema]

Comment: Creating a surrogate (`AddressId`) is *not* normalization, but a design choice to decrease disk space utilized (query performance will be about the same/slightly worse).  With disk space so cheap is there a urgent need to do this?

Comment: @bbaird I would like to have only one table to just store address data if I need to update or change the address.

Comment: David - once an address is created, it *must be* immutable.  For instance you shouldn't go changing shipping addresses for orders that have already shipped or for customers that haven't initiated the change.